Traefik ForwardAuth middleware is not enabled in a simplified Docker Compose example
I'm trying to adapt this example, https://github.com/thomseddon/traefik-forward-auth/blob/master/examples/traefik-v2/swarm/docker-compose.yml, to run a simplified example of Traefik ForwardAuth middle using Docker Compose. Here is my docker-compose.yml:
version: "3.3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v3.1"
    command: --providers.docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  whoami:
    image: "traefik/whoami"
    container_name: "simple-service"
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whomai.middlewares=traefik-forward-auth"

  traefik-forward-auth:
    build: ./auth
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-forward-auth.forwardauth.address=http://traefik-forward-auth:4181"
      - "traefik.http.services.traefik-forward-auth.loadbalancer.server.port=4181"
    ports:
      - "4181:4181"

Here I have the following directory structure,
.
├── auth
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── authserver.go
│   └── go.mod
└── docker-compose.yml

where authserver.go reads
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Println("Received an auth request.")
        if strings.TrimSpace(strings.Replace(r.Header.Get("Authorization"), "Bearer", "", 1)) != "me" {
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusUnauthorized), http.StatusUnauthorized)
            return
        }
    })
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":4181", nil))
}

and its Dockerfile
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM golang:1.23

WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod ./
RUN go mod download
COPY *.go ./
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o /authserver
EXPOSE 4181
CMD ["/authserver"]

If I run this using docker-compose build && docker-compose up, an I cURL whoami.localhost, I just get a response:
> curl whoami.localhost
Hostname: b1cef814f323
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 172.19.0.2
RemoteAddr: 172.19.0.4:39164
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: whoami.localhost
User-Agent: curl/8.7.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.65.1
X-Forwarded-Host: whoami.localhost
X-Forwarded-Port: 80
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Forwarded-Server: 51b71ba0a1e6
X-Real-Ip: 192.168.65.1

However, I would expect to get a 401 Unauthorized response as the request doesn't have the Authorization: Bearer me header required by the ForwardAuth middleware.
By contrast, if I cURL the middleware service directly, I get the expected response and can see from the Docker logs that traefik-forward-auth's endpoint is being called:
> curl http://localhost:4181
Unauthorized

Any idea why the ForwardAuth middleware appears to not be working on requests to whomai.localhost?

It seems strange this works at all, as Docker is opening the ports for Traefik, but there are no entrypoints defined.

Note that using :ro on the bind mount of a socket (/var/run/docker.sock:ro) does not work as intended, it implies security that does not exist. The socket needs to be read and written to, as it is similar to http. For improved Docker socket security, you need a proxy.

The issue was that the middleware needs to be defined under the whoami service. I simplified the example a bit by just running the authorization server locally (using go run authserver.go) and setting the forwardauth.address to use the host.docker.internal host:
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"

  whoami:
    image: traefik/whoami:latest
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.localhost`)
      - traefik.http.middlewares.whoami-auth.forwardauth.address=http://host.docker.internal:4181
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.middlewares=whoami-auth

Now if I cURL whoami.localhost with the expected Authorization header, I get the expected response:
> curl -H "Authorization: Bearer me" whoami.localhost
Hostname: a00af0dc73a9
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: ::1
IP: 172.18.0.2
RemoteAddr: 172.18.0.3:44122
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: whoami.localhost
User-Agent: curl/8.7.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: Bearer me
X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.65.1
X-Forwarded-Host: whoami.localhost
X-Forwarded-Port: 80
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Forwarded-Server: 0187136d9fd9
X-Real-Ip: 192.168.65.1

whereas without it, I get Unauthorized per the authorization server's implementation:
> curl whoami.localhost
Unauthorized

I can also see from the Traefik API that the middleware is enabled:
> curl --silent http://localhost:8080/api/rawdata | jq '.middlewares'
{
  ...
  "whoami-auth@docker": {
    "forwardAuth": {
      "address": "http://host.docker.internal:4181"
    },
    "status": "enabled",
    "usedBy": [
      "whoami@docker"
    ]
  }
}

